# Moznaim Nahardea Edition vs Oz VeHadar

Tags: jewish-books, shas

How does the accuracy of the new print Moznaim Nahardea Shas compare to that of the Oz VeHadar Shas?

Comment: Accuracy as compared against what standard?

Comment: Did you often run into errors in Oz veHadar?

Comment: I simply mean which one contains more errors? I know Oz VeHadar put a lot of effort into cleaning up the text of the Talmud, but I'm not sure how it compares to other publishers' editions of Shas, such as Nahardea

Comment: Sometimes Oz Vehadar goes too far, and includes alternate versions that are inferior to the accepted text.

Comment: I use the oz v'hadar extensively and often find small mistakes in the marginal matter. Hagaot HaBach without a header, wrong pasuk in torah ohr, doubled pasuk in torah ohr, a letter that doesn't appear to refer to anything, Rashis not in the mussaf Rashi (I don't know if they make that or someone else does). ...  I have not found many mistakes in the text of the gemara itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have rarely found any errors in Oz V'hadar, (Nahardua is also very clean but I've bumped into errors like שלש-שלשה when dealing with אמות-טפחים, which lead to a bit of confusion...)

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: How many pages have you learnt? Could you point at specific errors?